# Run Code First Migration Seed Method without a migration

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

How do you run a code first entity framework migration without changing anything in the datamodel which would cause a migration to be created? I just want to run the seed method again because I added things to it.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you just need to run `Seed()` again, and nothing has changed that would cause a new migration to be added, just call `Update-Database` again with no flags and it will say 'No pending migrations', and run `Seed()` again for you. `Seed()` is called every time the DB is updated, regardless if there are new migrations or not.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work it's a Down() migration via `Update-Database -TargetMigration foo`.  Do you know of how Seed() could be manually run in that case?

Comment: @twm Just saw this: Feel free to make a separate question and I can explain more, but `Seed` doesn't get called during a down migration, only up. You can however grab a reference to the context inside of a migration and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: it didn't work. I see the running Seed method, publish to azure and the table is still empty.

Comment: @user1019042 it's pretty hard to diagnose with just that information. You should create a new question.

Comment: Seed() is only called when the migration is executed from the command line

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "Seed() is called every time the DB is updated, regardless if there are new migrations or not" => specifically, how can the DB be updated without a new migration?

Comment: @vbp13 you can update data in the database by using the `Seed()` method. Like I said in the answer, if you call `Update-Database` and there are no pending migrations, it will still fire off `Seed()`

Comment: Not sure what about EF Core, but in EF 4.1.3 `Seed` is called only when there are any model changes. Repeated `Update-Database` calls have no affection, but "Running Seed method" message is still shown.